# Horizontal SUMIFS with two vertical criteria

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2016

I am given the following sales table which provide the sales that each employee made, but instead of their name I have their ID and each ID may have more than 1 row.

To map the ID back to the name, I have a look up table with each employee's name and ID.

Sales Table:

| Year | ID | North | South | West | East |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | A | 58 | 30 | 74 | 72 |
| 2020 | A | 85 | 40 | 90 | 79 |
| 2020 | B | 9 | 82 | 20 | 5 |
| 2020 | B | 77 | 13 | 49 | 21 |
| 2020 | C | 85 | 55 | 37 | 11 |
| 2020 | C | 29 | 70 | 21 | 22 |
| 2021 | A | 61 | 37 | 21 | 42 |
| 2021 | A | 22 | 39 | 2 | 34 |
| 2021 | B | 62 | 55 | 9 | 72 |
| 2021 | B | 59 | 11 | 2 | 37 |
| 2021 | C | 41 | 22 | 64 | 47 |
| 2021 | C | 83 | 18 | 56 | 83 |

ID table:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| A | Allison |
| B | Brandon |
| C | Chris |

I am trying to sum up each employee's sales by a given year, and aggregate all their transactions by their name (rather than ID), so that my result looks like the following:

Result:

| Report |  |
| --- | --- |
| 2021 |  |
| Allison | 258 |
| Brandon | 307 |
| Chris | 414 |

I want the user to be able to select the year, and the report would automatically sum up each person's sales by the year and their name.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With FILTER:

```
=SUM(FILTER($C$2:$F$13,($B$2:$B$13=INDEX($I$2:$I$4,MATCH(N3,$J$2:$J$4,0)))*($A$2:$A$13=$N$2)))
```

[image]

With SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$2:$F$13*($B$2:$B$13=INDEX($I$2:$I$4,MATCH(N3,$J$2:$J$4,0)))*($A$2:$A$13=$N$2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution Scott. It worked pretty well, until I encountered a name that had more than one ID associated with it. For example, let's say that Brandon was tied to both B and C, I don't think your formula would be able to capture all 2021 sales figures under B and C in the sales table. Do you know if this would be an entirely different question?

Comment: I assume that the INDEX and MATCH component of the formula falls through because it cannot establish a match when there are duplicate values?

Comment: It would be a new question.  Please make sure your test dataset is representative of your actual dataset.  That adds a level of complexity.  It is still possible with formula but would require some more thoughts.  Also when you ask the new question, please indicate the oldest version of Excel you need to work in.  As newer Excel will have different approaches to that question.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I've reposted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71469963/summing-an-array-of-values-based-on-multiple-criteria-and-look-up-table